# CakePHP2 CakeResponse::file() does not start download in Firefox

Tags: php, file, firefox, cakephp, download

I use CakeResponse::file() to let users download a file, as described here.

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file

However, I noticed it works fine in Chrome, IE, Opera, etc., except Firefox.  Just nothing happens in Firefox.

```
$this->response->file( $filepath, [
    'name' => $filename,
    'download' => true,
] );
return $this->response;
```

My controller's code is essentially like this.  It seems file type is irrelevant.  What's wrong with Firefox?

Comment: What's the exact problem on Firefox?

Comment: Download does not start.  No error.  Just nothing happens.

Comment: You probably need to mentioned the appropriate headers.

Comment: I assume CakeResponse::file() sets up all necessary headers.  If it is not the case, I'm not sure what to do and would like to get some advice.

Comment: I think you may find the solution by comapring the response headers under chrome and firefox, there might be something missing for firefox and chrome just don't need it!

Comment: Can you give further more informations (file type, version of firefox ...). it seems to work fine for me on firefox dev 52

Comment: I use CentOS 7.2, Apache 2.4.23, PHP 7.0, CakePHP 2.9.5. My Firefox is 50.1.0(newest) but the problem occurs in other users' Firefox (version unknown) as well.  File types that I tried so far are jpg, zip, mp4, png, but I guess file type is irrelevant.

Comment: What is the value of ```$filename```? I could be that there are problems with the filename itself.

Comment: I checked $filename and my conclusion is that it shouldn't be a problem.  My guess is that some kind of special headers are needed for Firefox but I don't know what they are.

Comment: No headers received in FF either? Are you checking the inspector?

Comment: You must receive **some** response, so check your response headers and content. If you **don't** receive a response, the problem can't be in FF. (Can't download something if nothing is received)

Comment: @mmrn I replicate your code in my file. It is working fine in both firefox and chrome. I am able to download it get request. If you are calling your function in ajax to download it will show in response instead of downloading.

Comment: Looks like FF is not receiving headers in the inspector. I just don't see it but am not 100% sure about it (I may be looking at wrong pane)

Comment: I found the solution.  I was sending a password through POST to initiate a download and it was causing the problem somehow.  After changing it to a normal link it works fine in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a [link](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links) to download file like this, it will work in all browser. **TESTED**

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Download', 
  array('controller' => 'Home',
  'action'=>'download'));
?>
```

Code in your Home controller

```
  public function download() {
    $this->response->file( $filepath, [
     'name' => $filename,
     'download' => true,
    ] );
   return $this->response;
  }
```

If you call this download functon by ajax it will show the file in response instead of downloading.

Comment: May I know why someone downvoted my answer? If someone is downvoted, give atleast the reason.

Comment: This was it. I was sending a password through POST to initiate a download, not using a normal link from the view.  I changed it to a link and now it works fine in FF and Chrome.

Comment: that's what I wrote in my answer. It should be a normal link.

Comment: Yes, this answer worked and was awarded.  I don't know why someone downvoted it.